# Mockk with context receiver

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I'm trying to use Mockk to mock a method with context receiver:

```kotlin
class MyClass {
    // The method I'm going to mock
    context(CallContext)
    fun myMethod(a: Int) Int { a }
}
```

It's hard to get the instance of CallContext in the unit test. So I hope I can write a unit test in this way:

```kotlin
/* 
This should work, but I can't get the CallContext instance 
with(callContextInstance) {
    Every { mockedMyClass.myMethod(1) } returns 2
}
*/

// I hope a unit test can be written like this... But it won't compile now.
with(any<CallContext>) {
    Every { mockedMyClass.myMethod(1) } returns 2
}
```

So what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If I get the idea what exactly do you try to mock, the following works with mockk 1.13.3:

```kotlin
interface CallContext

class MyClass {
    context(CallContext)
    fun myMethod(a: Int): Int = a
}

class ContextMockTest {
    private val myClassMock: MyClass = mockk()

    @Test
    fun mockContextWorks() {
        every {
            with(any<CallContext>()) {
                myClassMock.myMethod(any())
            }
        } returns 123

        val context = object : CallContext { }

        with(context) {
            assertEquals(123, myClassMock.myMethod(1))
        }

        verify {
            with(any<CallContext>()) {
                myClassMock.myMethod(1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A [link](https://gist.github.com/motorro/66348d27f93f1f54c4689f77ba07555b) to the gist just in case

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, MockK [does not support context receivers](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/995), and it probably won't until context receivers are released - so some time after Kotlin 1.9, so maybe in 2024).

(Context receivers are explicitly described as [not ready for production](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1620.html#prototype-of-context-receivers-for-kotlin-jvm). A stable release won't be available until [after the K2 release](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10468), and the [K2 beta is targeted for Kotlin 1.9](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52604), which has a planned release of December 2023.)

That said, if anyone wants to attempt support, then get stuck in! MockK is an community supported open source project that accepts PRs.

#### Confounding factors

However, there are two hinderances before MockK can fully support context receivers:

- Context receivers aren't finished, nor is their current implementation stable. [KT-10468](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10468). Their implementation could change significantly. Trying to implement support for a  moving target is challenging.
- IDE support is limited, which makes developing with them difficult (follow [KTIJ-20857](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-20857/Full-context-receivers-IDE-support) for updates)

#### Workaround

In the meantime, you could adjust your code to allow for manual mocking.

First, adjust `MyClass` to either be an open class, or introduce a new interface that describes the behaviour you want to mock ([code to an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/4161471)).

```kotlin
/** Describe the API that [MyClass] will implement */
interface MyClassSpec {
  context(CallContext)
  fun myMethod(a: Int): Int
}
```

And then implement the interface

```
/** Concrete implementation of [MyClassSpec] */
class MyClass: MyClassSpec {
  context(CallContext)
  override fun myMethod(a: Int): Int = a
}
```

Now in your test you can create a mock by creating an [anonymous object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#inheriting-anonymous-objects-from-supertypes) that implements `MyClassSpec` - and now you have a mock that supports context receivers.

```kotlin
@Test
fun myTest() {
  val myClassMock = object : MyClassSpec {
    context(CallContext)
    override fun myMethod(a: Int): Int = 123
  }
}
```